# Normalizing nested responses in ngrx

Tags: angular, normalization, ngrx

I am fairly new to ngrx and I am not sure what the best practices are regarding normalizing nested objects.

Let say the store is defined as follow:

```
export interface User {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   surname: string;
}

export interface Transaction {
    id: string;
    amount: number;
    owners: []
}

export interface TransactionState {
    ids: string[];
    entities: { [id: string]: Transaction }
}

export interface UserState {
   ids: string[],
   entities: { [id: string]: User }
}

export interface CapitalState {
  transactions: TransactionState;
  users: UserState;      
}
```

The first way I thought of implementing this is, is in the effect where the data is normalized and then two actions are dispatched to update the users and the transactions

```
@Effect()
transactions$ = this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(fromTransactionsActions.TransactionsActionTypes.LoadTransactions),
   concatMap((action: fromTransactionsActions.LoadTransactions) =>
      this.transactionsService.loadTransactions(action.payload).pipe(
         map((tranactions: TransactionView) => {
             //Normalize Data
             return [ //Dispatch Transactions Load Success
                      //Dispatch Users Load Success];
         }),
         catchError(error => of(new fromTransactionsActions.TransactionsLoadFailure("")))
        ))
    )
```

The second is to dispatch the normalized data in one Transaction Load Success action and then to update the state from there.

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, action: TransactionsActions): CapitalState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TransactionsActionTypes.AllotShareCapitalSuccess:
            return {
                ...state,
                transactions: { ...state.transactions, ...action.payload.entities.transactions },
                users: { ...state.users, ...action.payload.entities.users },
                error: ''
            };
```

I am not sure if these are best practices or if I am missing something. Are any of these good ways to do this? Are there better ways?

Comment: Are you loading everything from one service call?

Comment: No, but some posts do have nested objects that are only returned when they are created. This example is probably not the best since you would expect users be requested in a separate call.